# Bundler install permissions issue

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have cloned prawn and I am using a local version in a rails app. The gemfile contains the line:

```
gem 'prawn', :path => '/home/username/prawn'
```

This works fine if I am logged in as `username`, and run bundle install as that user. The problem is, I want to have a second user `usertwo` and install the forked version of prawn from the directory above.

I am using the exact same Gemfile, but when running bundle install I get:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - prawn-1.1.0.gem
```

`usertwo` has read access to the prawn directory, so I can't see why it would not be possible to use the local gem. Can anyone help get this working?

Comment: Could you show what the file system rights are to `prawn-1.1.0.gem` e.g. what does `ls -al /home/username/prawn/prawn-1.1.0.gem` show you - and can you `cat /home/username/prawn/prawn-1.1.0.gem` as the new user?

Comment: There is no .gem file in that directory, just a .gemspec. I'm not sure  why it's looking for a .gem file, and why the error is EACCES and not ENOENT.

Comment: It just occurred to me that must be trying to write the file to the directory (tyring to create a file in a directory I can't write to in irb produces the same error). I guess I do need write permissions to do this

Comment: why are you specifying the paths like that? why not use `gemsets` incase you are using rvm

Comment: I'm rewriting parts of the code, this is only for testing the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually down to the behaviour of bundler. When installing a gem, it creates the .gem file in the directory where the gem files are stored.

I am looking at the source code to see if a small patch might suffice to allow me to use local gems where I don't have write permission, will update if I am successful.